# Generate an auto increment function

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to figure out the best way to approach creating a function to generate random numbers at specific time intervals. I am using laravel and everything is new.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $date = new DateTime();
    
    while ($date){
        $date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $startIncrement  = $date;
        $stopIncrement = $date;
        $reportIncrement = $date ;
        $generator = rand(10,20);
        $randomServerStop = rand(5, $generator);
        $runningServers = "Started" ." ". $generator ." servers" ." " ."at" ." "  .$startIncrement;
        $stoppingServers = "stopped" ." ". $randomServerStop ." servers" ." " ."at" ." "  .$stopIncrement;
        $reportingServers = "Reporting" ." ". $generator ." servers" ." " ."at" ." "  .$reportIncrement;
        $response =  array($runningServers, $stoppingServers, $reportingServers);
        
        $response = json_encode($response);
   
        $Tasks = TaskType::create([
            'event' => $runningServers,
            "message" => $stoppingServers,
            "display_message" => $reportingServers,
            

        ]);
        return $Tasks ;
```

I am missing two crucial 'connectors' . 1, using PHP'S builtin date, how can I format it to always start 12 am. 2, since I have an startIncrement variable, I want this variable to be variable $date + 00:00:30(30secs) = 12:00:30 a task will run.
For example:

```
currentdate = new Datetime()
startIncrement = date(mktime(0,0,30)) ??
while true:
if timedate = 12:00:30
generator = rand(10,20)
echo "started " generator at 12:30
else:
"next task runs at" currentdate + startIncrement
```

Comment: Well, there is only one answer: CRON, see CRONTAB. However, and this is one of the reason I don't use `composer`, or similar: When invoked from CRON, all relative path gets wrong, it's garbage to me. This forces at the end to rewrite everything, without composer. The few time won on the beginning of a project, is a huge loss later. So, yes PHP and CRON are absolutely made to work together, but your packager is not. Can provide base example for CRON, if wanted. See https://crontab.guru/